# Partner center Get Resource name object level

Tags: rest, azure, api, powershell

I am currently working at an Powershell script that will automatically download the billing data from my companies CSP platform. I use following powershell module (https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-PowerShell) 
And use the following api(that the module calls I guess) To get the overall price from the last month of all my subscriptions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-subscriptions-resource-usage-information. With the Powershell module that is wonderfull I've managed to recieve good data from my Azure Resources and print them out in a CSV file for Power BI to create a report of them.
My question now is when I use power BI to create graphs of my cost and usage. I don't see the name of my resources (vm, storage, sql) instead I see names of the types (Read Operations,LRS Write Additional IO, ...) And of course that's also a good indicator. I would love to see the VM (the name of the vm or storage or sql) with the highest cost and usage not which type. The ResourceName in the response of the api is not exactly right.  The Resource name ( in Resource URL formatting) however is available with this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-customer-s-utilization-record-for-azure.
But here I cannot retrieve the cost of my Azure Resource. I tried to combine the 2 api's (one to retrieve the cost and the other one to retrieve the Resource URL with the Resource ID as a combiner) but strangly enough some customers have data in the usage api and not in the utilization api. So that didn't helped out well. My question today is: Is it possible to retrieve the resource name or URL with the response data i got from this api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-subscriptions-resource-usage-information . Or is there another way of providing the name of the object instead of the service.

Answer (score 1):

The resource usage feature will not return the resource name. So, you will need to combine data from [Get-PartnerCustomerSubscriptionUtilization](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/partnercenter/get-partnercustomersubscriptionutilization) and [Get-PartnerAzureRateCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/PartnerCenter/Get-PartnerAzureRateCard) to get the resource name and the partner cost associated with each billable meter. Since you are working with Power BI, it might be a good idea to check out [Partner-Center-Query](https://github.com/isaiahwilliams/Partner-Center-Query). It is another project that allows you query data from the Partner Center API through Power Query.

Comment: The utilization api is a good one. But not every customer provides me with data while the usage api does return usage data ? 
It would be nice if Microsoft just added the resource uri to the usage api. I am quite a newbie when it comes to Power BI so I will have a look at the Power Query but I am not sure at that fullfills my needs for this project :(